# Adding image in JApplet

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon, japplet

```
ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon("a.gif");
JLabel jLabel1=new JLabel(icon);
jLabel1.setVisible(true);
card1.add(jLabel1);
```

I am a newbie to Java and I am facing a problem to add image in a panel in applet.  My image is in the same folder.  My applet is visible without any problem but only image is not displayed.

Comment: `jLabel1.setVisible(true);`  If a component is added to a container that is made visible, it will be visible automatically.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763053/loading-image-in-java-applet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void init() 
    URL imageURL = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "a.gif");
    Image image = getImage(imageURL);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
    // ...
```

The `ImageIcon` constructor that accepts a `String` presumes the string represents the path & file name of a `File`.

Only trusted applets can access a `File`, and then only on the client file-system (not the server).  If this is an application resource, it should be on the server, and can be accessed by URL.

Note that the `ImageIcon` constructor will also accept an URL, rather than the `Image` used above.  I just wanted to highlight that applets have an inbuilt method to obtain images.

Comment: @mKorbel  I wish I had a dime for every time I've helped with this basic stuff.  ;)

Comment: hehehe new multi_dime_nsioner in AUD :-)