# Get applet to load pictures when user clicks on Level one

Tags: java, applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding image in JApplet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325389/adding-image-in-japplet)

I have my program compiled into one class file for an applet and it runs and works through java but when i added it into my html web page it will not load the pictures, i have all the pictures and the class and html page in one file and it loads the applet and i can click level one it just won't paint the pictures. Here is my code.

```
    import javax.swing.JApplet;

    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;

    import java.awt.Graphics;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class MainApplet extends JApplet {

public void init()
{
    LabelFrame frame = new LabelFrame();
}




public  class LabelFrame {


    public LabelFrame( ) 
    {

        int x = 500;
        // final LoadingPictures panel=new LoadingPictures();

        setSize(x,500);
        setLocation(350,200);

        setVisible(true);


        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JMenu Change = new JMenu("Pick a Level");
        menubar.add(Change);
            JMenu Move = new JMenu("Move keys");
        menubar.add(Move);

        JMenu Options = new JMenu("Options");
        menubar.add(Options);

        JMenu About = new JMenu("About");
        menubar.add(About);

        JMenu Select = new JMenu("Select");
        menubar.add(Select);



        final JMenuItem black = new JMenuItem("Black BackGround");
        Options.add(black);

        final JMenuItem blue = new JMenuItem("Blue BackGround");
        Options.add(blue);

        final JMenuItem yellow = new JMenuItem("Yellow BackGround");
        Options.add(yellow);

        final JMenuItem green = new JMenuItem("Green BackGround");
        Options.add(green);

        final JMenuItem white = new JMenuItem("White BackGround");
        Options.add(white);

        JMenuItem info = new JMenuItem("infomation");
        About.add(info);


        JMenuItem Level2 = new JMenuItem("Level 1");
        Change.add(Level2);



        final JRadioButton redBlock = new JRadioButton("redblock");


        final JButton moveleft = new JButton("Left");
        final JButton moveright = new JButton("Right");



        Select.add(redBlock);

        Move.add(moveleft);
        Move.add(moveright);



        Level2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {   
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event1)
            {

                final LoadingPictures levelpics1 = new LoadingPictures(1);

                add(levelpics1);

                //levelpics1.setVisible(false);
                //levelpics1.setVisible(true);
                revalidate();
                //repaint();

            //Move the redblock right
                redBlock.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {   
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent rightselect)
                    {
                        moveright.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                    {   
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent right)
                        {
                            if (LoadingPictures.topone ==400)
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have won the level now move to next level");
                            }
                            else
                                {LoadingPictures.topone+= 50;

                            levelpics1.repaint();}


                        }});
                    }});

                //Move the redblock left
                redBlock.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {   
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent leftselect)
                    {
                        moveleft.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                    {   
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent left)
                        {
                            if (LoadingPictures.topone == 0)
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can not move left anymore");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                LoadingPictures.topone-= 50;

                            levelpics1.repaint();
                            }

                        }});
                    }});




                  int delay3 = 500; //milliseconds
                  ActionListener taskPerformer3 = new ActionListener() {
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                          if(LoadingPictures.level2topleft == 0)
                            {
                                LoadingPictures.level2topleft+=325;
                                levelpics1.repaint();
                            }


                            else 
                            {
                                LoadingPictures.level2topleft-=25;
                                levelpics1.repaint();
                            }

                      }
                  };
                  new Timer(delay3, taskPerformer3).start();



                  int delay2 = 1000; //milliseconds
                  ActionListener taskPerformer2 = new ActionListener() {
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                          if(LoadingPictures.topleftone == 0)
                            {
                                LoadingPictures.topleftone+=325;
                                levelpics1.repaint();
                            }


                            else 
                            {
                                LoadingPictures.topleftone-=25;
                                levelpics1.repaint();
                            }

                      }
                  };
                  new Timer(delay2, taskPerformer2).start();



                int delay11 = 750; //milliseconds
                  ActionListener taskPerformer11 = new ActionListener() {
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                          if(LoadingPictures.level2topfor4block == 300)
                            {
                                LoadingPictures.level2topfor4block-=300;
                                levelpics1.repaint();
                            }


                            else 
                            {
                                LoadingPictures.level2topfor4block+=25;
                                levelpics1.repaint();
                            }

                      }
                  };
                  new Timer(delay11, taskPerformer11).start();






                black.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        levelpics1.setBackground(Color.black);

                    }});
                blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        levelpics1.setBackground(Color.blue);

                    }});
                yellow.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        levelpics1.setBackground(Color.yellow);

                    }});
                green.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        levelpics1.setBackground(Color.green);

                    }});
                white.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        levelpics1.setBackground(Color.white);

                    }});

            }


        });






        info.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {   
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"•This is our     Final project for computer programming 3 \n" +
                                                "•\n•Based off of the " +
                                                "game by KIRA GAmes called UnBlock Me");
                            }});


    }

}



public static class LoadingPictures extends JPanel{

    ImageIcon block2vertical = new ImageIcon ("2block.jpg");
    ImageIcon block4vertical = new ImageIcon("4block.jpg");
    ImageIcon redblock = new ImageIcon("redblockhorizontal.jpg");

    ImageIcon Level2block4 = new ImageIcon("Level2block4.jpg");
    ImageIcon Level2block2 = new ImageIcon("Level2block2.jpg");
    static  int top = 0;
    static  int topone = 0;
    static  int topleft = 200;
    static int level2topleft = 200;
    static int topleftone = 225;
    static int topfor4blockvertical = 150;
    static int level2topfor4block = 150;
    private int j;
    public LoadingPictures(int i)
    {
        super();
        j = i;



    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (j == 1)
        {


            g.drawImage(redblock.getImage(),topone,200,this);
           g.drawImage(Level2block4.getImage(),350,level2topfor4block,this);
        g.drawImage(Level2block2.getImage(),100,level2topleft,this);
            g.drawImage(Level2block2.getImage(),200,topleftone,this);

        }
        else if(j == 2)
        {


        }
    }




}
     }
```

and this is the line of code i have in my html that loads the applet

```
    <applet code ="MainApplet.class" height = "500" width = "500"></applet>
```

Comment: [Do you get any errors when you run the applet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886783/how-do-i-view-error-messages-for-my-java-applet) Where are the files stored that you are loading? Does your applet have the correct security permissions to access them?

Comment: My files are stored in the same folder i have the mainApplet.class in, No i do not get errors when i run the applet it works fine through java and what do you mean by security permissions?

Comment: Consider having a read through [Reading/loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763053/loading-image-in-java-applet) for possible help

Comment: Check out [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) for details about security issues with applets. In this particular case, you shouldn't need to worry as long as the image files are on the same server as the applet.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not asking about errors when you run your applet locally via the command-line or an IDE. Do you get any errors (which are displayed in the Java console) when you run the applet in a web browser from the server where you uploaded it?

Comment: No i do not get any errors, and i will look through those the links you have posted, and try to see if it make it work

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Yes, that is also a duplicate. +1

Comment: @Code-Guru  Good advice on the console & browser differences in security.  Trying to develop applets without the console in view is like to trying to fight while blind-folded.