# My java applet will not display anything, no syntax errors

Tags: java, applet, type-conversion

I have a final project for computer science due tommorow, this works as an application but won't display anything as an applet which is what we need it to be. (it was coded as an app then converted to an applet)

i dont undertsand how this whole posting code things works on this site so i put it on pastebin.com
    http://pastebin.com/kiFmzbfp

Is there in which I could run a jar using an applet?

Comment: is there in which i could run a jar using an applet?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there in which I could run a jar using an applet?

Yes.  Though it is not the best way to go about showing a GUI from an applet.

Add the Jar to both the compile-time & run-time class-path (int the `archive` attribute) of the applet.  Within the applet `init()`, remove `start();` and add the code within the current `main(String[])`.  Vis.

```
UserInterface runner = new UserInterface();
runner.Interface();

MainCode run = new MainCode();
run.Change_InterFace();
```

Preferably that code should be called on the EDT  (Event Dispatch Thread). See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

But the code will have problems as an applet, since it attempts to access resources by `File` rather than `URL`.  This has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14309301/418556) in the last 24 hours.

---

Noting that is 443 lines of code dump at the paste bin,this is as far as I am prepared to investigate.  You have ..around 17 hours left till the dead-line, so you'd better get cracking.

Comment: And as an aside.. *"as an applet which is what we need it to be."*  Given this is a school project suggests that was from the instructor.  Please ask them from me, to kindly join us in the 3rd millennium & specify an app. launched using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS can launch frames and applets free floating, or in recent times, also embed applets in web pages.  But there has to be a very good reason to cram a rich client (Swing) into a thin client (HTML).  This is not one of them.  If they actually stated ""must be available on the web"* do w. JWS.